# Very slow transfer speeds from and to SD cards on my high end PC

Tags: usb, file-transfer, sd-card

A friend just came over and wanted me to copy a video I made on my Smart Phone Camera to his SD card. So I popped his SD card into this [Anker USB hub](https://www.anker.com/products/a8346) and connected it via USB C port to my computer, which is USB 3.2 Gen 2. In my PC I only have SSDs, no HDDs.

The transfer speed was very slow. It copied with 10mb/s which seemed to take forever. I thought it was his SD card that was just bad, but he later sent me a picture showing that on his laptop, he reached transfer speeds of 100 mb/s.

So I tried various different combinations of different SD cards, adapters, cables, and phones and with *every* combination I tried, I only ever get speeds of 10 to 12 mb/s. Here are some examples:

- Phone via USB C to PC. Copied a file to phone internal and SD card: 10 mb/s
- Phones SD card on an SD to USD adapter (USB 2) to PC: 10 mb/s
- SD card on my Anker adapter to USB C: 10 mb/s.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be here? It really bothers me that when I want to copy *anything* from my phone to the PC, I get such low transfer speeds.

The only thing I can think of is that my friend has an SD card reader on his laptop and maybe that's why it's faster on his laptop? But that would mean that SD cards can never copy faster than 10mb/s if connected via USB. That can't be true, right?

---

**Edit**:

- Transfer speeds to any other SSD or HDD which are connected via USB are normal.
- Even if I connect an HDD to the Anker hub (USB 3) and then into the PCs USB C port (USB 3.2), the speeds are normal as far as I can tell (ca. 120 mb/s)

So it's just when connecting an SD card or my Android Phone to the USB port of my PC that causes these problems.

Comment: Sounds like you just have a slow SD card. They're not massively fast to begin with.

Comment: Writing to an SD card will always be slower than reading from it. A "U10" card only guarantees that it can write at 10MB/s. The marketing will claim "up to 100MB/s!!!!111!1!!" but that is only the read speed. Him showing that it was reading at 100MB/s tells you nothing,

Comment: Thanks for answering. Let me clarify again:

I copied a file from my PC to his SD card: 10mb/s -->

He copied the same file to his laptop: 100 mb/s

Comment: Yes. You **wrote** to the SD card at its 10MB/s. He **read** from the SD card at 100MB/s. That is absolutely normal and expected for SD cards. Awful write speeds, okay read speeds.

Comment: But when I copy the same file to my PC again the transfer speed is also just 10mb/s

Comment: @Sirius; I suggest you edit the question and remove confusing statements. Read speeds should be compared to read speeds, not to write speed. Tests need to be using identical hardware, so ideally with the Anker on his device, using exact same SD card. As it is, it seems we're on a wild goose chase.

Comment: OK, got it. I will do some further testing. Thanks!